# Import class twice under different names

Tags: python

The story is simple. I want to import class under different names twice.
The rationale for this is good looking api.

```
# This class enhances other classes with convinience methods
# I own this class
class CssMixin:
    def add_css_class(self, name: str):
        # Code to add css style to self
```

In another file:

```
# import class twice as Mixing and as Helper class
from breaffy.helper import CssMixin as Helper, CssMixin

# Enrich class with convinience methods
# ExternalClass is class from some third-party library
# And is not under my control
class MyClass(ExternalClass, CssMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.add_css_class("button-class")

        # another instance of ExternalClass
        # often used in GUI libraries 
        self.child = ExternalClass()

        # Here not to duplicate all GUI class hierarchy 
        # to use method as a helper and pass original ExternalClass as self
        Helper.add_css_class(self.child, "label-class")
```

1. Is this correct and standard approach in Python?
2. What other solutions to do the same?
3. Is it possible to monkey-patch original class, so that all classes derived from `ExternalClass` will automatically have `add_css_class` method (without adding mixins)? Is this approach better?

Comment: Are you the author of `breaffy.helper`? It could do the aliasing `Helper = WidgetOpsMixin`. I'm not sure the aliasing helps but this approach is not unheard of.

Comment: Calling a `WidgetOpsMixin` method on an object that isn't an instance of `WidgetOpsMixin` seems like an abuse of the type system. (Also, it fails on Python 2, so watch out if there's any chance you'll have to support Python 2.)

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should usually inherit from mixins _first_: `class MyClass(CssMixin, ExternalClass):`. Most of them are designed to work that way and might break if you don't use them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? You can simply make an alias for the existing `CssMixin` variable.

```
from breaffy.helper import CssMixin as CssMixin
Helper = CssMixin

# Rest of the code ...
```

Comment: What is the difference and pitfalls from original multiple import?

Comment: @likern I wanted to provide a different way to do the same thing. To my knowledge, those statements have the same effect - your choice will be a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes are going to be used in different ways then it seems more pythonic to separate them into two different classes that maybe inherit from a parent class. That will make documentation a lot clearer too.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood you correctly. Could you give some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

I think your interface is unintuitive. Especially the invocation like

```
Helper.add_css_class(self.child, "label-class")
```

is questionable. Someone reading your code will wonder why you're calling a classmethod on a completely unrelated object instance. In python, classes aren't used as namespaces. When a python programmer sees a function call like `class.method(...)`, they automatically assume that there's a strong connection between that method and the class (for example, the method could return an instance of that class). But this is not the case in your code.

To reduce the confusion, I would split the interface into a function and a mixin class:

```
def add_css_class(obj, name: str):
    # Code to add css style to obj

class CssMixin:
    def add_css_class(self, name: str):
        add_css_class(self, name)
```

Which means your module would be used like this:

```
from breaffy.helper import CssMixin, add_css_class

class MyClass(CssMixin, ExternalClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_css_class("button-class")

        self.child = ExternalClass()
        add_css_class(self.child, "label-class")
```